# Web Part Sharepoint 2010 using WSDL - how to connect it together?

Tags: sharepoint

I need to activate custom feature in Sharepoint 2010.

When I go to Site Actions -> Manage site features and click Activate button I get the error that says something like "this feature can only be installed on pages for for meeting workspace". The exact error ID is: a06f1d31-f84a-4033-980d-5d8cdbea0189.

Do you know how to activate this feature in some other way, maybe over Power Shell?
I have already tried things like this: http://www.greggalipeau.com/2011/08/23/sharepoint-2010-powershell-enabledisable-feature-for-all-site-collections/

But, as I am using VS 2012 for my project, Power Shell says that I can't use .NET Framework 4.0 with this feature that I am trying to activate.

What to do? Is there other way of activating a feature? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Go to project properties and set build version of your project to .net framework 2.0/3.5. Once done, rebuild and deploy your solution again.

To enable a feature in powershell you need `Enable-SPFeature -Identity "FeatureGUID/FeatureFolderName" -url "url of the site collectino of site"`